# Progress bar to automatically detect how many times it will be incremented

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm sure I'm going about this incorrectly but, my program has a progress dialog which alerts the user of the current progress.

I would like my code to dynamically calculate the Max value of a progress Dialog.

Currently, my progress dialog works by knowing in advance the total phases (the max value).

For example, I have the following

```
private ProgressDialog _pd;

public void DoThis()
{
    _pd.SetTotalPhases(3);
    DoSomething();
    _pd.Update();
    DoSomethingElse();
    _pd.Update();
    AndFinally();
    _pd.Update();
}
```

This works fine, everything is confined and it's easy to manage and read.

The issue I have is, the pd.Update() will occur all over the place and not in 1 small method.

What I'd like to do is, some how, never explicity set the total phases manually as I do in the example both. I'd like to only use `_pd.Update();` and some sorcery works out the max value.

The only way this could work in my mind is, if I could get the compiler (I assume compiler) to read my code in advance, find every instance of _pd.Update() and count them. This then will provide my Max value in my progress dialog.

Then, I can have a simple bit of logic in the _pd.Update() which simply increments the current phase value.

My own search has not shown me much, I suspect due to my use of terms/phrases.

I can see pitfalls already with this, for example I will have to be careful how I use the _pd.Update() because if I used the following then I would have incorrect results (despite the code below being nonsense)

```
if (boolValue)
    _pd.Udate();
else
    _pd.Udate();
```

Does something already exist for this in .NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always split your tasks up in to actions and add them to a list, each one can be run and your progress bars value incremented one by one.

```
        // This will keep track of how many tasks have been completed.
        int progress = 0;

        // create a list of the tasks to be completed.
        List<Action> tasks = new List<Action>();
        tasks.Add(new Action(() => DoSomething()));
        tasks.Add(new Action(() => DoSomethingElse()));
        tasks.Add(new Action(() => { /* you can either put code in here */ }));
        tasks.Add(new Action(() => { /* or call a method with your task in */ }));

        // your progress bar's max value is now tasks.Count

        // then loop over them one by one and complete them
        foreach (var task in tasks)
        {
            task.Invoke();

            // Progress bar.Value = progress
            progress++;
        }
```

Comment: +1 for a very nice and clean solution, bare in mind that user should call `update()` when iterating through the methods.

Comment: This approach is definitely worth the effort. Perhaps you could wrap this approach in a class and expose methods to register a task and provide a mechanism so that task can signal the completion or fault if required and update the progress bar as necessary.

Comment: Actions can be defined with strongly typed return values as well so it would be quite easy to return a value that shows if the operation was successful.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that it is not possible to guess the exact number of calls made to a certain method for various reasons, I am trying to list a few

below are concerns for calls made to _pd.Update() but not limited to the list

- calls made in conditional structs eg. if-else, switch and even try-catch
- call are made in a loop for which terminating condition is decided at run-time i.e. via user input
- calls are made via external consumer of the library
- calls are made via reflection which are nearly impossible to count.

Comment: Yes, I know there will be limitations, and the Loop **will** be a major factor, but, these are things I can control I think. I could  decide not to call _pd.Update() in a loop or an else statement etc.

Comment: reflection is limited to MSIL stream, which may be very difficult to parse, however you may use [Cecil](http://mono-project.com/Cecil:FAQ) to some extent. But think twice if the effort made is worth doing it. you may end up writing a lot more code then what you do now.